# Clarification in a proof of integrability

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

This proof for the Integrability of Thomae's function is a little unclear to me.

> The irrational numbers are dense. Thus for any partition $P$ ={ $x_0, x_1, x_2, ...x_n$}
> there is always an irrational in every interval $[x_{i-1}, x_i]$. thus $L(t, P)=0$.
>
> To prove that $t$ is integrable it is enough to show that for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a partition $P_{\epsilon}$ with $U(t, P) < \epsilon$.
>
> Let $A_n =${$ x: t(x) \ge \dfrac{1}{n}$} . It is easy to show that $A_n$ is finite.
>
> Suppose  $\epsilon >0$. choose $n$ such that $1/n<\epsilon/2$. now choose a partition $P_\epsilon$  such that "each point of $A_n $ is in the interval $[x_{i-1}, x_i]$ where  $\triangle x_i< \dfrac{\epsilon}{2 |A_n|}$"[continued]

The last statement of is unclear to me due to the fact that $\epsilon$ is arbitrarily small here , which implies that we might take $\triangle x_i$ as small as we want,then how would it contain all the points  of $A_n$?

The second one is due to the ambiguity of notations. What is the connection between $i$ and $n$? What does it mean that 'each point of $A_n $ is in the interval $[x_{i-1}, x_i]$'?  Does it mean that each point of  $A_i$ is in the interval $[x_{i-1}, x_i]?$

Comment: @BaronVT http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~marker/math414/rint.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The exposition in the proof is a bit sloppy. It should read "$\ldots$ now choose a partition $P_\epsilon$ such that each point of $A_n$ is in **some** interval $[x_{i-1},x_i]\ldots$ ", i.e. for each point of $A_n$ there is an $i$ such that the point lies within the interval $[x_{i-1},x_i]$.

Further down in [the document that you referenced in your comment](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~marker/math414/rint.pdf), the proof should read (if I understand it correctly): "Note that $|B^c|\le |A_n|$. If $i\in B$ then $M_i<\frac1n<\frac\epsilon2$, while if $i\notin B$ then $M_i\le1$."